# Matching Numbers after string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a very simple string I am trying to match but can't seem to get it working. I want to match some numbers after a string and also emit the trailing %.

```
encodeTime=10%
```

I have tried look ahead but it doesn't seem to work. It just matches the entire string.

```
(?=encodeTime=)[^\s]+
```

Is there a way I can just match the numbers only and also emit the % after?

Comment: You couldn't find a regex that just matches a series of numeric digits?  Did you look?

Comment: What do you mean by `emit`, do you mean `omit` ?

Comment: How about `encodeTime=(\d*)`  ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a lookbehind for this purpose and this `(?=encodeTime=)` is not a valid positive lookbehind.

```
(?<=encodeTime=)\d+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cE1vZ2/1)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any kind of lookaround assertion for something as simple as this. Use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and use the **Match.**[Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property to reference the group and print your match result.

```
String s = "encodeTime=10%";
Match m  = Regex.Match(s, @"encodeTime=(\d+)");
if (m.Success)
   Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value); //=> "10"
```